# running local host openfire and smack client library andorid

Tags: java, android, smack

I installed openfire local server on my laptop and using smack library as `xmpp` client. I followed [this](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-2/) and 
[this](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/57209).
After running code I dont see any exception and I don't understand if my user is connected to `server`. Is there any way to check connection .

Code for making connection to server
  XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        config.setUsernameAndPassword(loginUser, passwordUser);
        config.setServiceName(ConnectXmpp.DOMAIN);
        config.setHost(ConnectXmpp.DOMAIN);
        config.setPort(5222);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

```
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    Log.e("connection",""+connection);//this line to check connection
```

XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
        connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

2. I added user at server and using that username for login at app side.
3. please guide me where i can check incoming messages fromclient to server , im using embedded database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your callback listener; it will return the connection object.

Comment: Is it possible to check connection at server end? I have 2 chat app so i want to pass messages from client to server and from from server to client.

Comment: i logged connection object it is not null does it mean connection was sucesfully established? I have never worked on server side , so completely blank about managing server end, i updated my answer for showing connection code.

Comment: yes your connection was established. you can use this connection object for further use. if you agree the make up voting for this answer